# Matlab: sorting a matrix in a unique way

Tags: algorithm, matlab, finance

I have a problem with sorting some finance data based on firmnumbers. So given is a matrix that looks like:

```
[1 3 4 7;
1 2 7 8;
2 3 7 8;]
```

On Matlab i would like the matrix to be sorted as follows:

```
[1 0 3 4 7 0;
1 2 0 0 7 8;
0 2 3 0 7 8;]
```

So basically every column needs to consist of 1 type of number.

I have tried many things but i cant get the matrix sorted properly.

Comment: Are all numbers unique for each row?

Comment: @patrik They need not be unique if you use a counting sort method and reproduce matrices from those counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer without assumptions - Simplified**

I did not feel comfortable with my old answer that makes the assumption of everything being an integer and removed the possibility of duplicates, so I came up with a different solution based on @lib's suggestion of using a histogram and counting method.

The only case I can see this not working for is if a 0 is entered. you will end up with a column of all zeros, which one might interpret as all rows initially containing a zero, but that would be incorrect. you could uses `nan` instead of `zeros` in that case, but not sure what this data is being put into, and if it that processing would freak out.

**EDITED**

Includes sorting of secondary matrix, B, along with A.

```
A = [-1 3 4 7 9; 0 2 2 7 8.2; 2 3 5 9 8];
B = [5 4 3 2 1; 1 2 3 4 5; 10 9 8 7 6];

keys = unique(A);
[counts,bin] = histc(A,transpose(unique(A)),2);
A_sorted = cell(size(A,1),1);
for ii = 1:size(A,1)
    for jj = 1:numel(keys)
        temp = zeros(1,max(counts(:,jj)));
        temp(1:counts(ii,jj)) = keys(jj);
        A_sorted{ii} = [A_sorted{ii},temp];
    end
end

A_sorted = cell2mat(A_sorted);
B_sorted = nan(size(A_sorted));
for ii = 1:size(bin,1)
   for jj = 1:size(bin,2)
       idx = bin(ii,jj);
       while ~isnan(B_sorted(ii,idx))
          idx = idx+1; 
       end
       B_sorted(ii,idx) = B(ii,jj);
   end
end
B_sorted(isnan(B_sorted)) = 0
```

Comment: I have tried your solution however it doesnt work for my dataset. (It works with my example). Maybe I should have explained how my dataset looks like in more detail. Im have a matrix with the smallest number being 10001 and 90756. The dataset contains approxinately 9000 different firms(colums) and 226 rows (months. The problem is I had to download the data a month at a time. So this means that the firms dont line up a nice timeseries. Also the matrix contains lots of zeros(much more than the number of rows).

Comment: Also i need to keep track of the firmnumber so that i can make a matrix that has all the returns that are associated with the firmnumber. Do you understand what I mean? Its hard for me to explain it in words.

Comment: Sorry it works, only have a lot of colums containing zeros!!! Now i only need to sort a corresponding matrix the same way as the firmnumber matrix is sorted.

Comment: @user3864684 that may be a bit more complicated, and not quite in the scope of your original question. I will have to think about how a second matrix can be sorted along with the original.

Comment: @user3864684 I have edited my answer to sort a second matrix along with the original one. and it will also not necessarily secondary sort if you have multiple of the same value in the original matrix.

Comment: @user3864684 if my answer helped solved your problem, consider an upvote and accepting an answer, so people know the question has been solved.

Answer (score 4):

```
A = [1 3 4 7;
     1 2 7 8;
     2 3 7 8;]

%// Get a unique list of numbers in the order that you want them to appear as the new columns
U = unique(A(:))'

%'//For each column (of your output, same as columns of U), find which rows have that number. Do this by making A 3D so that bsxfun compares each element with each element
temp1 = bsxfun(@eq,permute(A,[1,3,2]),U)    

%// Consolidate this into a boolean matrix with the right dimensions and 1 where you'll have a number in your final answer
temp2 = any(temp1,3)

%// Finally multiply each line with U
bsxfun(@times, temp2, U)
```

So you can do that all in one line but I broke it up to make it easier to understand. I suggest you run each line and look at the output to see how it works. It might seem complicated but it's worthwhile getting to understand `bsxfun` as it's a really useful function. The first use which also uses `permute` is a bit more tricky so I suggest you first make sure you understand that last line and then work backwards.

Comment: You need to transpose the `U`.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 My bad, typed `;` instead of `'` when defining `U`

Comment: @Dan I figured it was something simple like that, just wanted to give a heads-up :)

Comment: Smart approach with `bsxfun`! Got a weakness for it. +1

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking can also be seen as an histogram

```
 A = [1 3 4 7;
     1 2 7 8;
     2 3 7 8;]
uniquevalues  = unique(A(:))   
N = histc(A,uniquevalues'  ,2)                             %//'               
B = bsxfun(@times,N,uniquevalues')                         %//'
%// bsxfun can replace the following instructions: 
%//(the instructions are equivalent only when each value appears only once per row )
%// B = repmat(uniquevalues', size(A,1),1)                    
%// B(N==0) = 0
```

Comment: me neither but you can trick it by adding a comment with a `'`. I'll edit as a demonstration

Comment: This is also a clever approach! You can use `bsxfun` instead of `repmat` here, it's usually more efficient: `bsxfun(@times,histc(A,U  ,2),U')`

Comment: wow, that instruction replaces my last 4 lines, I should really start to learn bsxfun!

Comment: @lib Did few edits for the comments. Hope they look okay to you.

Comment: @lib Be careful with edits, one more edit and the UP points won't add to your rep, if you care about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create at the beginning a matrix with 9 columns , and treat the values in your original matrix as column indexes.

```
A = [1 3 4 7;
1 2 7 8;
2 3 7 8;]

B = zeros(3,max(A(:)))
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    B(i,A(i,:)) = A(i,:)
end
B(:,~any(B,1)) = []
```

Comment: Just add a line to delete the columns of `0` at the end to get my +1 (i.e. `B(:,any(B))`)

Comment: yes, I don't know why I was considering only single digits

Comment: if I use U then the indexing gets messed up because the values of U are not always continous.  I am using U in my histogram answer, thanks!

Comment: you're right, my bad. In that case I would recommend against this approach because if one of the numbers is big, say `100000`, you're going to waste a lot of memory. I like your histogram method the best.

Comment: @Dan if memory is a concern, try jumping to using a map container, and essentially a modified counting sort. I have updated my answer to show this method.

Comment: besides having the memory problem, this approach works only with positive integers.